# Controlling externally Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ipc

It is possible to send commands to a running instance of *VLC media player* through Unix domain sockets.

I was wondering if *Google Chrome* has a similar protocol or API to send commands to a plugin?

Specifically I want to build a Chrome extension which intercepts the button press of my earphone and pauses the video, if one is being streamed. I need a way to  inform Chrome about the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this is usually done (e.g. EA Battlelog) is a local websocket server that your extension's JavaScript communicates with.

On the server side, check out [websocketd](http://websocketd.com/) which works with any programming language.

For the extension side, you want to use the websocket API built into JavaScript:

- http://websocketd.com/#tutorial
- https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/